# PWA app update alert in angular6

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6, progressive-web-apps

I have developed a PWA app in angular6 with @angular/pwa and it is working absolutely great. I am also trying to notify the user to update the PWA app when user opens the app if there is any update in the app. I have gone through different articles and blogs, and find [this](https://medium.com/progressive-web-apps/pwa-create-a-new-update-available-notification-using-service-workers-18be9168d717) article, but it is not for angular6. I am unable to add any eventListeners as service workers are automatically created. Please help me in resolving this issue. Thank you!

Comment: https://alligator.io/angular/service-worker-updates/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with SwUpdate service like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class UpdateService {
    constructor(swUpdate: SwUpdate) {
        swUpdate.available.subscribe(event => {
            // notify user that update is available
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it's working fine. Thanks for the response :-)